# How do i fill all arguments of a function/class with 0?

Tags: python

Assuming i have a class `Student()`, with multiple arguments, how would i fill all the arguments with 0, regardless of how many arguments there are.

i was thinking to use *args like this:

`Student(*0)`

but that didnt work.

Comment: Redesign the class, e.g. with keyword arguments that have a default of 0.

Comment: Non-keyword arguments are mandatory. If you don't know how many arguments the `__init__` method of a class has, you have a more general problem (e.g., bad documentation).

Comment: If the function has a `*` parameter, it accepts, in a sense, "optional" positional arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Explicit is better than implicit. If you want to set each parameter to 0, do so explicitly.

```
s = Student(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)  # E.g., 5 arguments
```

If you want to hide that from the caller, provide a class method makes the call for you.

```
class Student:
    ...

    @classmethod
    def from_zeros(cls):
        return cls(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

s = Student.from_zeros()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Student.__init__` doesn't have any keyword-only arguments, you can use

```
n = Student.__init__.__code__.co_argcount - 1 # subtract 1 for "self"
s = Student(*[0]*n)
```

Comment: For completeness, `co_argcount` doesn't take a `*` parameter into account.

Comment: @chepner yes, I think this works as intended, because you cannot "fill" `*args` with zeros.